# How can I map a dictionary to pandas DF (column of lists)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

[enter image description here[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPo4j.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz705.png)

Here is the DF I want to map this dictionary to attr_indices but map and replace don't work on lists! is there anyway I can map this dictionary to that column?

I tried DF['attr_indices'']=temp.replace(Dicto, inplace=True) but doesn't work on lists

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
DF['attr_indices_new'] = DF['attr_indices'].apply(lambda x: [Dicto.get(y,y) for y in x])
```

Or:

```
DF['attr_indices_new'] = [[Dicto.get(y,y) for y in x] for x in DF['attr_indices']]
```